Loading an email template into a vuetify app
I am displaying email from an outlook email using MS Graph API. The content of the body is in html format so I am trying to add it via the v-html prop such as:
<div v-html="emailContent">

However, because the email has styles in it then its impacting the styling of my app such as the sidebar icons and things like that. Is there a way to contain the styles inside the div only?

Have you tried using an iframe?

I saw that in a comment about that for a similar question but no answer was provided. Could you post a response of how to do this? When I tried to do an iframe and set :src equal to the html string it just put a small box on the screen.

It's been a while, but I think you can use the srcdoc attribute to specify html. Something like this: <iframe :srcdoc="emailContent"></iframe>. Here's the docs: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp

Did that resolve your issue, @Qiuzman?

Yea for some reason I just get an empty box. Il have to try again. Also, I hate the box look. Can the recess be styled so it doesnt show the border? Assuming it can be but just confirming.

Sure, this thread has some helpful information about iframe styling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

iframe is working as intended. However, I for the life of me cannot get the container to show the full height of the content. I tried:            

If I leave scrollbar then it shows all the content. Makes no sense since height is set to 100 percent

Weird... I'm not sure I can help without seeing the rest of the code. I'm glad it is working otherwise though.

Also, I'm going to move this solution to an official answer so that others don't have to sift through our conversation if they're looking for an answer in the future. I'd appreciate it if you mark it as accepted if it's resolved the original issue.

Use an iframe with the srcdoc attribute to avoid the email styles interfering with your webpage styles:
<iframe :srcdoc="emailContent"></iframe>

This thread has further helpful information about iframe styling.
